# Memory Dump for Android/Java in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, debugging

Is there a way to view memory in raw hex data in the Eclipse/Android debugger?  I have a very large byte array.  I can examine it but the values are hard to view as a list and are displayed as signed decimal values.

What I am looking for is a memory examiner to view this array as a memory dump of unsigned hex values similar to what you find in the MS Visual C++ debugger.  And yes, I know there are no unsigned primitive types in java.

Has anyone found a solution to this?